# Converting Image to Color array

Tags: java, arrays, image, colors

I load an image in Java and want to convertit to a RGB-Array so I can read the color of each single pixel. I searched on Google, but I only found how to convert Color-Arrays to Images.

Comment: Check out the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html, specifically `getRGB()`.

Comment: How can I convert Images into BufferedImages?

Comment: How are you loading your `Image`? Most likely you can just pass a `BufferedImage` instead.

Comment: Or you can cast your `Image` as `BufferedImage`. If you post your code where you load you image, I can be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines illustrate the usage of the API methods:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read( new File( "image.png" ) );
int[] data = ( (DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {
    Color c = new Color(data[i]);
    // RGB is now accessible as
    c.getRed();
    c.getGreen();
    c.getBlue();
}
```

If you face issues due to the color model, create a copy first

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage( bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );

img2.getGraphics().drawImage( bi, 0, 0, null );
```

and use img2 in the above code.

Comment: Does img strand for the Image i want to convert?

Comment: @user2241553 sorry that was a mistake, I fixed that.

Comment: why is `data.length` larger than `img.width*img.height` ?

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis thats because width*height is the number of pixels and a pixel can have more than a byte. (RGB values plus alpha deoending on the type e.g.  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)