# Why isn't BufferedImage recognized as a valid symbol?

Tags: java, image, compiler-errors, bufferedimage

I was trying to do what was proposed here: [Converting Image to Color array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881413/converting-image-to-color-array)

The code that I copied:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read( new File( "image.png" ) );
int[] data = ( (DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {
    Color c = new Color(data[i]);
    // RGB is now accessible as
    c.getRed();
    c.getGreen();
    c.getBlue();
}
```

I changed "image.png" to "BA 0091.jpg" in my code.

Code:

```
public class BANCPU{
  public static void main(String[] Ugh){
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read( new File( "BA 0091.jpg" ) );
    int[] data = ( (DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {
      Color c = new Color(data[i]);
      // RGB is now accessible as
      c.getRed();
      c.getGreen();
      c.getBlue();
    }
  }
}
```

Errors that I got:

```
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 3]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BufferedImage
  location: class BANCPU
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 3]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ImageIO
  location: class BANCPU
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 3]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class File
  location: class BANCPU
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 4]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DataBufferInt
  location: class BANCPU
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 6]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Color
  location: class BANCPU
File: C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\prgm clas\java junk\BANCPU.java  [line: 6]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Color
  location: class BANCPU
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Because you didn't import it. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import a few libraries to make that program work.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
```

Add those lines to the top of your program and it should work.

Comment: That led to some other problems....
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
 at BANCPU.main(BANCPU.java:9)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)`

Comment: Code:
`import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
public class BANCPU{
  public static void main(String[] Ugh) throws IOException{
    byte P[] = new byte[1408];
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read( new File( "BA 0091.jpg" ) );
    int[] data = ( (DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
    //System.out.println(data.length);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ) {
      Color c = new Color(data[i]);
      // RGB is now accessible as
    }
  }
}`